# Duda sentencia MERGE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando hacer un merge para insertar|actualizar|borrar en una tabla de una base de datos B con los datos proporcionados de un select de varias tablas de una base de datos A.

```
MERGE [B].[dbo].[Ventas] AS DLH
USING ( SELECT [A].dbo.Clientes.Nombre, [A].dbo.Precio.Dinero..........
```

pero los select de la base de datos [A] aparece subrayado en rojo y dice

> The multi-part identifier [A].dbo.Clientes.Nombre could not be bound

y si ejecuto la query dice

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Clientes'.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿? Más que el MERGE en sí, parece cuestión del SELECT (¿has probado a ejecutarlo fuera del MERGE?) En todo caso los campos generalmente (¿nunca?) se referencia jerárquicamente dentro del SQL, lo que se referencia jerárquicamente es la tabla y los campos hacen referencia a las tablas definidas en el FROM. Lo dicho, céntrate en la SELECT.

Comment: Y por cierto, si quieres ayuda con una instrucción SQL, deberías escribirla COMPLETA en vez de hacernos jugar a las adivinanzas. Mira [ask].

Comment: Esto no parece estar asociado al merge. ¿Seguro que el usuario con el que estás conectado tiene acceso a la base de datos [A]? ¿Existe la tabla dbo.Clientes en la base de datos [A]?

Answer (score 0):

Una parte del problema puede radicar en la cache del intellisense.

```
CREATE DATABASE [A]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [B]
GO
use [A]
GO

Create Table dbo.Ventas (id int, valor varchar(10))
go
Insert into dbo.Ventas (id, valor)
values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b');
go
Use [b]
go

Create table compras (id int, col varchar(10))
go
insert into compras (id, col)
values
(2,'c'),
(3,'d');
go
```

Si estás usando B puedes escribir la sentencia:

```
Merge compras as DLH
USING (
    SELECT id, valor  FROM [A].dbo.Ventas
    ) as source (id, columna)
    on DLH.id =source.id
when Matched then 
    update Set DLH.col = source.columna
When not Matched by Target then
    Insert (id, col)
    Values (source.id, source.columna)
When not Matched by Source then
    Delete;
```

Y la misma es funcional.

[image: Resultado]

Pero el intellisense puede no haberse enterado aún, bien por el cambio de bases o porque sea necesario refrescar la cache (Ctrl+r). No obstante el error es más probable que se deba a una sintaxis incorrecta.

[image: Intellisense]

[Sentencia Merge. Como se hace](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/)